# ggplot error on aesthetics on predicted values of Regression in R

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a graph of predicted values in ggplot.The script is depicted below -

Program1

```
lumber.predict.plm1=lm(lumber.1980.2000 ~ scale(woman.1980.2000) +
                        I(scale(woman.1980.2000)^2), data=lumber.unemployment.women)
xmin=min(lumber.unemployment.women$woman.1980.2000)
xmax=max(lumber.unemployment.women$woman.1980.2000)
predicted.lumber.all=data.frame(woman.1980.2000=seq(xmin,xmax,length.out=100))
predicted.lumber.all$lumber=predict(lumber.predict.plm1,newdata=predicted.lumber.all)



lumber.predict.plot=ggplot(lumber.unemployment.women,mapping=aes(x=woman.1980.2000,
                                       y=lumber.1980.2000)) +
geom_point(colour="red") +
geom_line(data=predicted.lumber.all,size=1)
lumber.predict.plot
Error: Aesthetics must either be length one, or the same length as the   dataProblems:woman.1980.2000
```

I believe, we do not need to match the number of observations in base dataset with the one in predicted values dataset. The same logic/program works when I try it on 'cars' dataset.

```
speed.lm = lm(speed ~ dist, data = cars)
xmin=10
xmax=120
new = data.frame(dist=seq(xmin,xmax,length.out=200))
new$speed=predict(speed.lm,newdata=new,interval='none')
sp <- ggplot(cars, aes(x=dist, y=speed)) +
   geom_point(colour="grey40") + geom_line(data=new, colour="green", size=.8)
```

The above code works fine. 
Unable to figure out the problem with my first program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same y value in the predicted data. Change this line

```
predicted.lumber.all$lumber=
        predict(lumber.predict.plm1,newdata=predicted.lumber.all)
```

by this one :

```
 predicted.lumber.all$lumber.1980.2000=   ## very bad variable name!
     predict(lumber.predict.plm1,newdata=predicted.lumber.all)
```

Or recall `aes` as :

```
geom_line(data=new,aes(y=lumber),
  colour="green", size=.8)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That was silly mistake on my part.. :(  The error message did not give any clue regarding variable names.

Thanks again!!

Comment: The error message is explicit. ggplot2 can't find lumber.1980.2000 in your new data so its length is zero different of the length of x aes which is length(woman.1980.2000).

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that in your code,

```
...
geom_line(data=predicted.lumber.all,size=1)
...
```

`ggplot` does not know which column from `predicted.lumber` to use. As @agstudy says, you can specify this with `aes(...)` in `geom_line`:

```
...
geom_line(data=predicted.lumber.all, aes(y=lumber), size=1)
...
```

Since you're just plotting the regression curve, you could accomplish the same thing with less code using:

```
df    <- lumber.unemployment.women
model <- lumber.1980.2000 ~ scale(woman.1980.2000) + I(scale(woman.1980.2000)^2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=woman.1980.2000, y=lumber.1980.2000)) +
  geom_point(color="red") +
  stat_smooth(formula=model, method="lm", se=T, color="green", size=0.8)
```

Note that `se=T` gives you the confidence limits on the regression curves.

Comment: I am not so sure if abline will work, because because its a polynomial regression and ends up producing a curve not a straight line.Let me know your thoughts!!

Comment: Yes you're absolutely correct! Sorry about that. I've edited the response to correct the mistake.